# Akka.NET Ask Task never completing

Tags: c#, akka.net

I may be doing something incorrect, but it is not apparent.  I have the following code:

```
 namespace test
    {
        class Program
            {
             static void Main(string[] args)

                {
                    using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("MySystem"))
                    {
                        var testPassRetriever = system.ActorOf<PrintActor>();
                        var task = testPassRetriever.Ask<PrintActorMsg>(new PrintActorMsg());

                        // prevent the application from exiting before message is handled
                        task.Wait();
                        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
        }
        class PrintActorMsg{}

        class PrintActor : ReceiveActor
        {
            public PrintActor()
            {
             Receive<PrintActorMsg>(msg => Console.WriteLine("foo"));
            }
        }
}// namespace test
```

The issue is that the Task returned by Ask never completes. Its status stays in the Waiting for Activation state.  "Foo" does get printed on the command line so I know the actor is processing the Print message.  Is there something else I am supposed to do in the overridden actor PrintMsg to mark the task completed?

Comment: Wouldn't Task.Run benefit you here?

Comment: I don't think so, I believe that the task is already running (handled by the Akka.net framework).  I am getting results of the task being successfully run.  I just wait for ever on task completion.

Comment: Try something like `Task.Run(async ()=> { /* your using statement */).Wait();` and see if that helps at all. And drop that `while (...)` and `task.Wait;` stuff.

Comment: I think that doing that would bypass AKKA.net and would not be helpful, since I am trying to use Akka.net to handle the multithreading for me.

Comment: The library will still manage threads just fine. Give it a try and see if it unblocks you.

Comment: It does not.  The wait call never returns.
Task.Run(() => testPassRetriever.Ask<PrintActorMsg>(new PrintActorMsg())).Wait();

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that you'll need to change `var task = testPassRetriever.Ask<PrintActorMsg>(new PrintActorMsg());` to `await testPassRetriever.Ask<PrintActorMsg>(new PrintActorMsg());`. Use of the await operator passes control to the scheduler allowing the task to run.

Comment: Additionally, you need that `async` keyword. Literally `Task.Run(async ()=> { /* setup code */ await testPassRetriever.Ask<PrintActorMsg>(new PrintActorMsg()); /* teardown code */ });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79364/discussion-between-whoisj-and-matt-johnson).

Comment: If I do that then then Console.WriteLine("Finished.") gets called before the message gets processed, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be using `await` / `async` with Akka.NET, because it can break the the "actors process one message at a time" guarantee.  Blocking with a `Wait` call is preferred here.  ( Source: https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-async-actors-using-pipeto/ ) -- The real problem is that you need to send a response (see @Martijn's answer below).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the ask pattern, but never send a message back. The ask task will only be completed when a message is received from the actor. The (sometimes advised) tell or fire-and-forget pattern doesn't do this.

Comment: I had to change the PrintActor to call 

Sender.Tell(new PrintActorMsg());

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness for future readers, since OP's original question didn't appear to want any response / result payload back from the called Actor, the OP should be using the `Tell` pattern, not `Ask`, e.g. for fire and forget dispatch scenarios:

```
 class PrintActor : ReceiveActor
 {
    public PrintActor()
    {
        // Response to the message, with no response
        Receive<PrintActorMsg>(msg => Console.WriteLine("foo"));
    }
 }
```

And in the calling program

```
var myActor = system.ActorOf<PrintActor>();
// One way 'fire and forget'
await myActor.Tell(new PrintActorMsg());
```

Whereas if Ask request-response type interaction is required, then the receive actor needs to provide a response via an explicit `Tell` back to the sender (`PrintResponse` is a new response message class):

```
 public class ResponseActor : ReceiveActor
 {
    public ResponseActor()
    {
       Receive<PrintActorMsg>(msg => {
         Console.WriteLine("foo"));

         // ... Other handling code here

         // Must return a response for an Ask
         Sender.Tell(new PrintResponse(), Self);
       });
    }
 }
```

And called like so

```
var response = await actor.Ask<PrintResponse>(new PrintActorMsg(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Note that adding [exception handling](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3834) is also a good idea.